# How calculate the global coverage?

Tags: python, django, code-coverage, tox, python-coverage

I am using [tox](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to test my [python egg](https://github.com/Yaco-Sistemas/django-inplaceedit). And I want to know the [coverage](https://coveralls.io/r/Yaco-Sistemas/django-inplaceedit).

But the problem is that the tests are executing with [python 2 (2.6 and 2.7) and python 3 (3.3)](https://github.com/Yaco-Sistemas/django-inplaceedit/blob/master/tox.ini) and some lines should be executed in python 2 and other in python 3, but this look like if only count the lines that are executed with python 2 (the last section in the tox, py26-dj12). You can see this here:

https://coveralls.io/files/64922124#L33

Of this way pass with the differents django version...

Is there some way to get the global coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I receipted an email answering this question:

> coverage.py (the tool coveralls uses to measure coverage in Python programs) has a "coverage combine" command.

Yesterday, I got the global coverage executing something like this:

```
coverage erase
tox
coverage combine
coveralls
```

In [tox.ini](https://github.com/Yaco-Sistemas/django-inplaceedit/blob/master/tox.ini#L7-8) I added the "p" param:

```
python {envbindir}/coverage run -p testing/run_tests.py
python {envbindir}/coverage run -p testing/run_tests.py testing.settings_no_debug
```

I fixed the problem with these commits:

- https://github.com/Yaco-Sistemas/django-inplaceedit/commit/200d58b2170b9122369df73fbfe12ceeb8efd36c
- https://github.com/Yaco-Sistemas/django-inplaceedit/commit/bf0a7dcfc935dedda2f23d5e01964e27f01c7461

Comment: Ah yes, just a single build with Tox for the various builds. However the build overview on Travis is lost this way, as there's only a single build.